# HasMany of Persistent Subclass while setting base coming back null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent

I have a class called Results. and a persistent counterpart called PersistentResults

```
class Results {
    public virtual IList<IHost> Hosts { get; set; }
}

class PeristentResults : Results {

    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<PersistentHost> Hosts
    {
        get { return base.Hosts as IList<PersistentHost>; }
        set { base.Hosts = value as IList<IHost>; }
    }
}
```

My hibernate mapping for my PersistentResult is this:

```
class ResultsMap : ClassMap<PersistentResults>
{
    Table("result");
    Id(i => i.ID).Column("id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();

    HasMany<PersistentHost>(r => r.Hosts).KeyColumn("resultid").Table("host").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
}
```

The class persists the Hosts to the database correctly, however bringing them back results in a null value.

Thoughts?

My solution was to fix the stupid typo I made a few days ago in the Host mapping.

oh bugger

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem and I remember I solved it by using `List<T>` instead `IList<T>`. It wasn't exactly the same scenario, but you can try.